# How do I update a SharePoint list via REST API in a script ran on another server for Sharepoint 2013 an also Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I need to update data in a sharepoint list remotely via a script that runs on a schedule.  We currently are using sharepoint 2013 foundation but will be moving to sharepoint online in 6 months or so. I would like to know how to do this via the REST api for both 2013 on prem and online versions.  Im having a hard time wrapping my head around all the different auth models, sharepoint products, available apis, frameworks etc and when reading the documentation on MSDN I cant be sure which is relevant to what version of sharepoint etc.. Anyway, so far im thinking or the 2013 on prem sharepoint I should use the High-trust certificate auth option so my script is authenticated via a certificate.  Do I need to create an add-in for script to register it as an app that will talk to the rest api?  The reason Im not sure is sharepoint itself never really has to call on my script and its not a webpart or page or antyhing that gets displayed on sharepoint so im a bit lost.

As for how to push data into sharepoint online lists, im assuming I would then have to register the script as a providor hosted Add-in and authenticate using OAuth2 via Azure ACS server.

Does this sound like the best way to acheive my goal? Am I on the right track or is their an eaiser option? Is there anyway I can just use a Active Directory user account in the script to make authenticated requests instead of having to create certificates trusts and create addins etc?

---

Update:

Heres some more info on what I'm trying to do...
The project Id like to start will be a Node or PHP script that runs on a seperate server and pulls data from a third party source, making calculations on it and then pushes the results into some Sharepoint lists. Then running this on a schedule every night to keep the Sharepoint lists up to date.  I know how to do everything except getting started with Sharepoint; how to establish the connection and authentication basically.

What id like to do is access the REST apis for lists and libraries from Node or PHP which would obviously be running externally to Sharepoint.  I just don't really understand how to get started.  My understanding is there is Sharepoint hosted apps (client side javascript that can access the SP apis), and provider hosted apps (which is essentially an iFrame to another web app).  So out of the two I'm looking at provider hosted, but do provider hosted apps only run when called? Do they need to present a front end to show in an iframe?  My project only needs to push data into lists overnight.  And so do I need to register the project as a provider hosted app??  Or how do I go about getting started?  And then I'm lead to believe that the app model is the 2013 way of programming for Sharepoint and the new 2016/online way is Sharepoint framework (SPFX). But then the only examples I'm seeing for this is client side apps.  The second project id like to do is to make a client side app which will take the data thats in the lists from project 1 and display that in certain ways dynamically using react. So I'm fairly comfortable knowing where to start for project 2, ill just straight into developing a client side react app that uses SPFX.  However I'm totally stuck on starting project 1. Where do I start for project 1? What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, You need to update your on prem list from schedular and later you will update the list in your sharepoint online.

We you can create a Provider hosted app and through configuration you can switch your destination easily.
OR you can think new way to do that. You can use Node JS timer service which insert to your on prem usign rest api later the same code will work for online you just need to change the destination.

Currenlty we are also donig it with Node. Below is the simple code to create timer in nodejs.

what is does, it read the crednentials from file and email to the user.It just a simple code and can be use to insert to SP list usign rest api.
https://github.com/halfice/Node-JS-Timer-SharePoint/blob/master/app.js

furthermore It would be more clarify if you could share picture of what you want to do

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me.  Ive added some more info to my original question if you can take a look? Thanks!